# Laptop won't receive power from it's power adapter

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

I have an ASUS K55VD with that's causing me some serious problems lately.

The problem is that even though the power adapter is connected and both it's led and the laptop's battery led are lit, the laptop isn't actually taking any power.

If I remove the battery and try to boot, it won't power on. If I connect the battery, then both Windows and Linux tell me that it is charging and even give me an estimate as to when this process will be over, but if I keep an eye on the power percentage I can see that it is actually decreasing, indicating that it is not using power from the wall but instead from the battery, and it doesn't charge it at all also.

I noticed this only today and I tested everything. I tested the power adapter on another laptop of a similar model (K55**... something) and it works there. I also tried to use that other laptop's battery and it's the same story (the batteries are the exact same model).

I also opened the laptop, removed the CMOS battery and held the power button pressed for well over a minute (unplugged and without battery, of course), but that didn't help - I can confirm that the BIOS was indeed reset as it's date was set to 1/1/2009 when I booted it with the battery on.

My laptop is about 3.5 years old and the only issue I had apart from that was the HDD that broke a few months ago, which I managed to fix by opening it and freeing the mechanical arm which got stuck, and then replacing it with an SSD (because it was failing and throwing errors).

EDIT: The service guy told me that the processor has to be replaced... but for me the processor works just fine even under heavy load, if I use a charged battery. He said it is unable to control and direct the flow of electricity from the AC adapter to the components and the battery. Is it possible? The CPU, as far as I know is responsible for performing logical and mathematical tasks. What does it have to do with power control? If there would be something wrong with it surely it would have been noticed while running it on the battery, right? I told him not to replace it, as it sounds fishy, and he only has a less powerful CPU available, an i5, and I really do need my i7 for my work.

Comment: I understand you tested the power supply with another laptop, but still you might want to try with another power supply. It could be a failing power supply, that for some reason still works on the other one but not this one. If not that, then it sounds like a motherboard electric failure which will likely require repair at a shop that has equipment to fix motherboards. You can disassemble but it's likely to be something you cannot fix at home.

Comment: Just done that. No change whatsoever :(

Comment: I sent it to a service and after a while they told me the CPU is the problem... but I have doubts... I mean, the laptop works fine with a charged battery, it can perform any kind of task I give, even play intensive games... it just won't draw power from the AC adapter... It's an i7-3610QM... they said they put an i5 in it and it charged, and then put the original CPU back in and the problem reappeared... but all of this sounds very strange to me. Can the CPU really be the problem, and if so is there really no way of repairing it or something?

Comment: I don't know as these things are very complex, maybe the different CPUs draw power differently. You could try another shop, maybe the one you took it to could not figure it out. You might have to replace a component on the motherboard to fix it.

Comment: That's what I'm planning to do after the holiday. I'm gonna search for a shop with good reviews and hopefully they will be able to figure out the problem and fix it for an affordable price. Thanks for your help.